# Deleting Particular repeated field data from Google protocol buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers

.proto file structure

message repetedMSG
    {
      required string data = 1;
    }

```
message mainMSG
{
  required repetedMSG_id = 1;
  repeated repetedMSG rptMSG = 2;
}
```

I have one mainMSG and in it too many (suppose 10) repetedMSG are present.
Now i want to delete any particular repetedMSG (suppose 5th repetedMSG )from mainMSG. For this i tried 3 ways but none of them worked.

```
for (int j = 0; j<mainMSG->repetedMSG_size(); j++){
                    repetedMSG reptMsg = mainMsg->mutable_repetedMSG(j);
                    if (QString::fromStdString(reptMsg->data).compare("deleteMe") == 0){
            *First tried way:-*  reptMsg->Clear();
            *Second tried Way:-* delete reptMsg;
            *Third tried way:-*  reptMsg->clear_formula_name();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

I get run-time error when i serialize the mainMSG for writing to a file i.e. when execute this line

mainMSG.SerializeToOstream (std::fstream output("C:/A/test1", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary))  *here i get run-time error*

Answer (score 5):

You can use `RepeatedPtrField::DeleteSubrange()` for this. However, be careful about using this in a loop -- people commonly write code like this which is O(n^2):

```
// BAD CODE! O(n^2)!
for (int i = 0; i < message.foo_size(); i++) {
  if (should_filter(message.foo(i))) {
    message.mutable_foo()->DeleteSubrange(i, 1);
    --i;
  }
}
```

Instead, if you plan to remove multiple elements, do something like this:

```
// Move all filtered elements to the end of the list.
int keep = 0;  // number to keep
for (int i = 0; i < message.foo_size(); i++) {
  if (should_filter(message.foo(i))) {
    // Skip.
  } else {
    if (keep < i) {
      message.mutable_foo()->SwapElements(i, keep)
    }
    ++keep;
  }
}

// Remove the filtered elements.
message.mutable_foo()->DeleteSubrange(keep, message.foo_size() - keep);
```

Comment: If I want to remove multiple elements, can I use "iterator 
erase(const_iterator position)"?

Comment: @Alan That will also be O(n^2) (just like it is on an std::vector).

Comment: i tried using DeleteSubrange in protobuf v2. but element from repeated field was not removed . i tried  for(int var = 0; var < foo.repeatedField_size(); var++)
      {
   foo.mutable_repeated_field()->DeleteSubrange(var,1);

      }

Comment: @ShivaniPahuja The code you wrote doesn't work because `DeleteSubrange()` changes the numbering of all subsequent elements, so `var++` will then skip an element. So you end up deleting every other elements. You need a `--var` like how I had `--i` in my first example. Also, your loop is O(n^2)...